# How we can clone any HTML element using drag then drop (html elements store in database and again getting elements from database)

Tags: jquery, html

after drag and drop, I want to store in the database using button click and again retrieve from form design from the database.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/5yd6uu45/20/

html

```
<div class="elements">
  <div class="new button-wrapper element ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" data-item-type="button">
    <span class="side-handle ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical"></span>
    <button class="" title="">New Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="new textbox-wrapper element ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" data-item-type="input[type='text']">
    <span class="side-handle ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical"></span>
    <input type="text" class="" title="" placeholder="New Textbox" />
  </div>
  <div class="new label-wrapper element ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" data-item-type="label">
    <span class="side-handle ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical"></span>
    <label class="" title="">New Label</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="drop"></div>

<div id="dialog-settings" title="Edit Settings">
  <p class="validateTips"></p>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="idValue">Element ID</label>
      <input type="text" name="idValue" id="idValue" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" data-attr-name="id" />
      <label for="titleValue">Element Title</label>
      <input type="text" name="titleValue" id="titleValue" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" data-attr-name="title" />
      <label for="titleValue">Element Class</label>
      <input type="text" name="classValue" id="classValue" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" data-attr-name="class" />
      <label for="innerText">Text</label>
      <input type="text" name="innerText" id="innerText" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" data-attr-name="text" />
      <label for="eventType">Event</label>
      <select id="eventType">
        <option></option>
        <option>onBlur</option>
        <option>onClick</option>
        <option>onChange</option>
        <option>onFocus</option>
      </select>
      <label for="eventValue">Script</label>
      <input type="text" name="eventValue" id="eventValue" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />

      <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
      <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

css
please attache

```
    .elements {
      margin: 3px;
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #666;
  position: relative;
}

.elements div.element {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  margin: 0;
}

.side-handle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  cursor: grab;
}

.top-handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  cursor: grab;
}

.top-settings {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.top-delete {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: -16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form-wrapper form {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 19px;
  border: 1px dashed #222;
  padding: 1px 3px;
}

#drop {
  width: 500px;
  height: 340px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin: 3px;
}

#drop div.element {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px;
  padding-top: 16px;
  margin: 0;
}

#drop div.element form,
#drop div.element button,
#drop div.element input,
#drop div.element label {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#dialog-settings {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

#dialog-settings label,
#dialog-settings input {
  display: block;
}

#dialog-settings input.text {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  width: 95%;
  padding: .4em;
}

#dialog-settings select {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  width: 95%;
}

#dialog-settings fieldset {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.ui-dialog .ui-state-error {
  padding: .3em;
}

.validateTips {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.3em;
}
```

jquery

I am doing work on drag and drop in HTML 5. Someone suggested to me to use jquery-ui because they have lot of stuff already implemented.

I am able to drag and drop any HTML element only in one column right now, but I want to be able to clone any HTML element from one column to another column. I want the original element to stay in its origin column as well.

This concept is shown in this example.

In this example, "test" div can be cloned and dropped anywhere, but I to be able to drop it only in the "drop" column - it can be dropped anywhere in this column.

After dropping, I also want to resize it, change the position, save the properties such as size, width, height, etc in a file or Database.

```
var tmpElement;
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.new').draggable({
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid"
      });

      $('#drop').droppable({
        accept: ".new",
        drop: function(e, u) {
          var a = u.helper.clone();
          console.log("INFO: Accepted: ", a.data("item-type"));
          a.appendTo("#drop");
          makeId(a.find(a.data("item-type")));
          a.removeClass("new");
          a.find(".side-handle").remove();
          var handle, set, rem;
          handle = $("<span>", {
            title: "Double-click to resize",
            class: "top-handle ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-horizontal"
          });
          set = $("<span>", {
              title: "Click to Edit settings",
              class: "top-settings ui-icon ui-icon-gear"
            })
            .click(function() {
              var $wrpr = $(this).parent();
              var elType = $wrpr.data("item-type");
              var $tElem = $wrpr.find(elType);
              var inText = $tElem.text().trim();
              var elId = $tElem.attr("id");
              var elTitle = $tElem.attr("title");
              var elClass = $tElem.attr("class");
              var elEvent = false,
                elScript = "";
              switch (true) {
                case $tElem.is("[onblur]"):
                  elEvent = "onBlur";
                  break;
                case $tElem.is("[onclick]"):
                  elEvent = "onClick";
                  break;
                case $tElem.is("[onchange]"):
                  elEvent = "onChange";
                  break;
                case $tElem.is("[onfocus]"):
                  elEvent = "onFocus";
                  break;
              }
              if (elEvent) {
                elScript = $tElem.attr(elEvent);
              }
              if (elType == "input[type='text']") {
                inText = $(this).parent().find(elType).attr("placeholder");
              }
              tmpElement = $(this).parent().find(elType);
              console.log("INFO: Editing " + tmpElement.prop("outerHTML"));
              $("#dialog-settings #idValue").val(elId);
              $("#dialog-settings #titleValue").val(elTitle);
              $("#dialog-settings #classValue").val(elClass);
              $("#dialog-settings #innerText").val(inText);
              if (elEvent) {
                $("#dialog-settings #eventType").val(elEvent);
                $("#dialog-settings #eventValue").val(elScript)
              }
              $("#dialog-settings").dialog("open");
            });
          rem = $("<span>", {
              title: "Click to Delete element",
              class: "top-delete ui-icon ui-icon-close"
            })
            .click(function() {
              $(this).parent().remove();
            });
          a.append(handle, set, rem);
          a.addClass('dropped').draggable({
            containment: "#drop"
          }).dblclick(function() {
            // Enabled Resize on element when double clicked
            var thisEl = $(this).data("item-type");
            $(this).resizable({
              alsoResize: ".dropped " + thisEl
            });
          });
        }
      });

      $("#dialog-settings").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 425,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
          "Update": saveEl,
          Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
          }
        },
        close: function() {
          $("#dialog-settings form")[0].reset();
          $("#dialog-settings .text").removeClass("ui-state-error");
        },
        open: function() {
          console.log("INFO: Settings Dialog opened.");
        }
      });

      $("#dialog-settings form").submit(saveEl);

      function saveEl() {
        var target = tmpElement,
          data = {};
        $("#dialog-settings .text").removeClass("ui-state-error");
        $("#dialog-settings .text").each(function(k, v) {
          data[$(v).data("attr-name")] = $(v).val();
        });
        if (data.id == null || data.id == "undefined" || data.id == "") {
          var c = $("#drop " + target.parent().data("item-type")).length;
          data.id = target.parent().data("item-type") + "-" + c;
        }
        if (validId(data.id)) {
          target.attr({
            id: data.id,
            title: data.title,
            class: data.class
          });
          if ($("#eventType").val() != "") {
            target.attr($("#eventType").val(), $("#eventValue").val());
          } else {
            target.attr({
              onBlur: "",
              onClick: "",
              onChange: "",
              onFocus: ""
            });
          }
          if (target.parent().data("item-type") == "input[type='text']") {
            target.attr("placeholder", data.text);
          } else {
            target.text(data.text);
          }
          $("#dialog-settings").dialog("close");
          console.log("INFO: Element " + data.id + " updated.");
        } else {
          $("#idValue").addClass("ui-state-error");
          updateTips("ID must be unique.");
        }
        return false;
      }

      function validId(str) {
        var valid = true;
        $("#drop div").each(function(k, v) {
          var el = $(v).data("item-type");
          var target = $(v).find(el);
          if (target.find("[id='" + str + "']").length) {
            valid = false;
            console.log("ERROR: Invalid Element ID.");
          }
        });
        return valid;
      }

      function updateTips(t) {
        $(".validateTips").text(t)
          .addClass("ui-state-highlight");
        setTimeout(function() {
          $(".validateTips").removeClass("ui-state-highlight", 1500);
        })
      }

      function makeId(t, str) {
        var c = $("#drop " + $(t).parent().data("item-type")).length;
        if (str == "undefined" || str == "" || str == null) {
          console.log("INFO: Generating ID.");
          if ($(t).parent().data("item-type").indexOf("input") == 0) {
            $(t).attr("id", "input-" + c);
          } else {
            $(t).attr("id", $(t).parent().data("item-type") + "-" + c);
          }
        } else {
          console.log("INFO: ID was passed.");
          $(t).attr("id", str);
        }
        console.log("INFO: Assigned ID '" + $(t).attr("id") + "' to " + $(t).parent().data("item-type"));
      }

      $(document).click(function() {
        if ($(".dropped").length) {
          // Disabled Resize on all elements when #drop
          $(".ui-resizable").resizable("destroy");
        }
      });
    });
```